# Given two twice-differentiable functions $f$ and $g$, use the chain rule to express the following derivatives of $u(x,t)=f(x+4t)+g(x-4t)$. In terms of

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given two twice-differentiable functions $f$ and $g$, use the chain rule to express the following derivatives of
\begin{align*}
u(x,t)=f(x+4t)+g(x-4t).
\end{align*}
In terms of $f, g, f', g', f'', g''$.

a) $u_x$ y $u_t$

b) $u_{xx}$ y $u_{tt}$

c) $u_t+4u_x$

d) $u_{tt}-16u_{xx}$

I'm a little confused with the notation, I guess. For example

$u_x=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(f(x+4t)\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(g(x-4t)\right)$

But how do I calculate $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(f(x+4t)\right)$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(g(x-4t)\right)$

They can explain. Thank you.

**I think it is:**

$u_x(x, t)=f'(x+4t)+g'(x-4t)$

$u_t(x, t)=4f'(x+4t)-4g'(x-4t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) We have
\begin{align*}
u_x=f'(x+4t)+g'(x-4t) 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
u_t=4f'(x+4t)-4g'(x-4t) 
\end{align*}
b) We have
\begin{align*}
u_{xx}=f''(x+4t)+g''(x-4t)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
u_{tt}&=16f''(x+4t)+16g''(x-4t) \\
&=16\left[ f''(x+4t)+g''(x-4t) \right] \\
\end{align*}
c) We have
\begin{align*}
4\left[f'(x+4t)-g'(x-4t)\right]+4\left[f'(x+4t)+g'(x-4t)\right] = 8f'(x+4t)
\end{align*}
d) We have
\begin{align*}
16\left[ f''(x+4t)+g''(x-4t) \right]-16\left[ f''(x+4t)+g''(x-4t) \right]=0
\end{align*}